# Regex: Match if link contains certain string only

Tags: regex

This is the regex I have:

```
\/web[^,:]*\.\w+
```

I want it to match

```
/web/src/app/reports/allLogs/test-list/test-event-history-list.component.spec.ts
```

but not this:

```
/web/src/app/reports/allLogs/test-list/test-event-history-list.component.ts
```

At the moment it matches both, but I want to contain `spec`. How to fix this?

[Link to the example.](https://regex101.com/r/Z6g7mS/1/)

Comment: What string must be present in match?

Comment: give some more examples

Comment: Your question is worded poorly. You need to explain why you expect certain things and expect to omit others.

Comment: Guys, it should contain the `spec` string in the link. Apologize for poor wording.

Comment: Are you saying you only want if spec is in the path? If so why use regex?

Comment: `/\/web[^,:]*?spec\.\w+/`

Comment: @anubhava, please make it an answer. I will upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
/\/web[^,:]*?spec\.\w+/
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z6g7mS/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead, just like this:

```
\/web[^,:]*\.(?=spec).*\w+
```